# requirejs setting up events in code

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

we started to use typescript and as it easily allows compiling into modules, we started with requirejs too. Is there a way to bind events directly in html? Like

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo.bar();">
    <img src="foo.png" alt="foo">
</a>
```

There is usualy no problem with setting it dynamicly

```
$("foo.selector").click((e) => {
    this.bar(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But we happen to have 2-3 pages where we have up to hundreds(thousnds) of table rows and up to 10 various events/row. And just setting up the events takes 0.5 seconds (may not look like a lot, but together with other page parts and stuff it is a lot). I already tried to move it to "on demand" setup where all lines had `mouseover => setup all the events` but that didnt work very well. I ran out of any optimization ideas but one, move the evnet binding into html and have them ready once the code is rendered. Anyway the inside of require block seems to be shielded from this behaviour.

Is there a way I could use it inside html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally it is considered pretty bad idea to use the event handling attributes like `onclick`, people are trying to move away from that approach.

if you need to handle clicks dynamically and you don't want (or can't) assign the event listeners directly to elements, consider using events delegation. kinda like that

```
$(document).on('click', "foo.selector", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log("You clicked:", this);
});
```

basically in this case you define an event listener on the `document` object it doesn't matter how many items of the specified type (if any) you have on the page. it also will automatically work with any new elements added to the page after you defined the listener.

Comment: Looks interesting, will check details and possible implementation for my scenario in few hours.